# Can't save on action create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have some problems with rails+mongoid to save on action create

I wrote the relations:

```
class SchoolClass
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes

  has_one :teachers

  field :nome, type: String

  validates_presence_of :nome, :message => 'Nao pode ser vazio'
end
```

and

```
class Teacher
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes
  belongs_to :school_class

  field :nome
  field :nascimento, :type => Date
  field :email
  field :senha
end
```

I created School class normaly.

To show the school classes:

```
    <%= f.input :school_class, :collection => SchoolClass.all, label_method: "nome", include_blank: false %><br />
```

TeachersController is:

```
  def create
    @teacher = Teacher.new(params[:teacher])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @teacher.save
        format.html {redirect_to(teachers_path, :notice => 'Professor cadastrado com sucesso')}
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html {render :action => :new}
        format.json { render json: @teacher.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I dont know how save the reference.
The Browser gime me this:

```
uninitialized constant SchoolClas
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: One wrong thing I found in your model is `has_one :teachers`. It should be `has_one :teacher` or `has_many :teachers`. I am not sure that is this solves your problem. Give some more info..

Comment: Does the error you posted have a typo or is it actually what you get? `SchoolClas` <-> `SchoolClas`

Comment: no, browser say: uninitialized constant SchoolClas
One letter 'S'.
I tried search on all application, bu I cant found 'schoolClas' on project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in SchoolClass, you should have:

```
has_one :teacher
```

Also, if your error message is correct, it looks like you may have mis-typed SchoolClass as SchoolClas somewhere (missing the final 's').

Comment: I changed to has_one :teacher, but the error is te same =(

The browser say the error on:

    teacher = Teacher.new(params[:teacher])

I need to do something different to get the parameter?

Comment: Do you perhaps have some custom inflectors that are turning SchoolClass => SchoolClas ?  
I've checked this in my own app (3.2.13 / ruby 1.9.3) and it works.

Comment: @JoshuaScott I suspect you may have had custom inflectors that was making it work.

Comment: @KyleKrull This was a brand new app, but I wasn't using Mongoid.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your form code as:

```
<%= f.input :school_class_id, :collection => SchoolClass.all, label_method: "nome", include_blank: false %><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html) states that "Model class name cannot end with "s", because it will be considered as the pluralized form of the word", and it suggests adding a custom inflector.

I had a similar situation with a class `XyzMass` being truncated to `XyzMas`.  Mongo was converting it to its corresponding table name - `xyz_mass` - and calling `String#singularize` on it.

Try putting the following in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.singular /(school_class)$/i, '\1'
end
```

You can test it in the Rails console with `'school_class'.singularize`.